# 2D Real time graphics in Java (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, swing, javafx, graphics, real-time-data

I'm developing a program that need to display 3 real time graphs, currently I'm working on IntelliJ but if needed I'll move to another IDE like NetBeans, I've been searching some options but I have no clear idea of the direction what would be the best for this kind of aplications.
This will be running on a windows bases enviroment

My observed options are trying JFreeChart but seems to be not so good for the real time nature, I haven't been able to find much documentation of JavaFX with this kind of application and idk how the java.awt.Graphics would work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [tag:jfreechart-fx] works well in this context; I typically focus on _collecting_ in real-time, limiting the burden on subsequent, interactive _display_; the same seems true in my experience so far for JavaFX charting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in real-time charting then you should have a look at this library: https://github.com/fair-acc/chart-fx
But doing real-time charts is more than just drawing something. It also involves data acquisition, data reduction, etc. You should do some research first in order to find the best solution for your specific problem.